# Braided metal hose in wall

Tags: plumbing

I'm renovating my bathroom and I was planning on chasing copper pipe in to the wall for a shower and a heated towel rail and then tiling over it. However I'm concerned about either there being a bad joint and it leaking or things not lining up properly.
So could I put braided metal hose in to the wall and the fill the cavity with fire foam? Am I right in thinking that this would be less likely to leak? Also does anyone know if this would comply with UK building regulations?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: That's a... *creative* solution. :) I'd look into Pex tubing. It's extremely easy to work with and a proven solution for plumbing. Otherwise, a bad sweat joint in copper is almost certain to show immediately. I've never seen one leak later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This flexible supply line hose is often called "braided stainless steel" tubing, but the SS is just armoring. The hose inside is some sort of rubber or elastomer. It will not last as long as copper, PEX, etc. and I must assume is not code approved for placement inside wall cavities. For one thing the connections are plastic seals which dry out or compress over time. They can only be used where they can be inspected without opening a wall.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll have a go with copper and then go for PEX if that doesn't work out.